# Same height li in multicolumn ul

Tags: html, css

I have created a muticolumn ul

The HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>Antelope</li>
   <li>Bison</li>
   <li>Camel</li>
   <li>Deer</li>
   <li>Eland</li>
   <li>Gazelle</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
 ul {
   float: left;
   width: 12em;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
 }

 li {
   float: left;
   width: 6em;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

Now if I add some more text in second li (or any li in second column) the whole row automatically resizes (height of row resizes). But if I add more text in first li (or any li in first column), whole row does not resize.

I want whole row to be resized if text is added or reduced in any li.

I copied above code from [this link.](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=27f87) You can see how multiple column ul works

Comment: Could you please show all the code for the multiple columns? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly a multicolumn unordered list is.

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole row automatically resizes"? Each `li` will be `6em` wide, regardless of the content inside.

Comment: I think he means the height of the 'row' resizes.

Comment: @thirtydot I meant to say that height of that row resizes.

Comment: @JackWilson you can see this link http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=27f87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add:

```
li:nth-child(odd){clear:left;}
```

to your CSS?

(This assumes you'll only ever want 2 columns)

Comment: It is working, thanks. i have 2 columns in my case but What if I have 3 columns?

Comment: I had problem with displaying products and their info (picture, price etc) in 2 columns. They were all in DIVs, i thought ul and li will solve my problem but using above on DIV solved whole issue

Comment: If you had 3 columns, you'd probably have to put each row into some kind of container like a `DIV` or `P` to keep them all level. And yes, `nth-child` is a CSS3 selector which won't work in any version of IE before IE9.